# SQL - Oracle - Same Field in Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, rows

I've got a student and a teacher table (only the respective *name* field is relevant). I want to sort it and then get a three column output.

Teachers

```
SELECT 'Aschauer' tName FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Auwald' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Berger' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beringer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bilek' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hanke' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lindner' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lenau' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mayer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pirkner' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Preissl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Siegel' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Walter' FROM DUAL
```

Students

```
SELECT 'Adler' sName FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kneippp' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Geyer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sitzenbleiber' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Huber' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Schulz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hundertwasser' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Berger' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Feuerstein' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mayer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sandler' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Graf' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Schlager' FROM DUAL
```

Expected result

```
Adler         Aschauer      Auwald        
Berger        Beringer      Bilek         
Feuerstein    Geyer         Graf          
Hanke         Huber         Hundertwasser 
Kneippp       Lenau         Lindner       
Mayer         Pirkner       Preissl       
Sandler       Schlager      Schulz        
Siegel        Sitzenbleiber Walter
```

Comment: Surely, you can take the effort to edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: I would like to edit the question, well that dont works, tried a few times now :/ I thought it is easy to understand.
I got Two Tables..One Studenttable with S_Name and one Teachertable with t_name.
Now i want to get all Names (teachers and student) in one output (as shown in the picture) ordered by alphabet and in 3 Columns.

Comment: Im sorry that i did not ask the question as Abecee did now, that was my first question on Stackoverflow and i didnt knew how to ask right. Next time it will be better, i promise ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the data from http://pastebin.com/xg1H9sT9

Tested in Oracle 11.2:

```
WITH
teacher AS (
  SELECT 'Aschauer' tName FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Auwald' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Berger' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Beringer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bilek' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Hanke' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Lindner' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Lenau' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mayer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Pirkner' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Prei' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Siegel' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Walter' FROM DUAL),
student AS (
  SELECT 'Adler' sName FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kneippp' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Geyer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Sitzenbleiber' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Huber' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Schulz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Hundertwasser' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Berger' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feuerstein' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mayer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Sandler' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Graf' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Schlager' FROM DUAL),
person AS (
  SELECT
    TRUNC((RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) - 1) / 3) rw
    , MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name), 3) cl
    , name
  FROM
    (SELECT tName name FROM teacher UNION
    SELECT sName FROM student))
SELECT
  one, two, three
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM person
    PIVOT(MIN(name) FOR cl IN (1 AS one, 2 AS two, 0 AS three)))
  ORDER BY rw
;
```

Not enough reputation to comment. Will thus respond here (and be brief)…

- `WITH` is here primarily for structure/readibility, yes.
- `RANK` reflects the order in numbers, which are needed for the ensuing calculation.
- `TRUNC` provides integers (which are easier to reference in the next step) for all quotients.
- "rw" and "cl" are for "row" and "column" respectively; indicating, what these columns are supposed to be used for later on. (But as "row" and "column" are reserved words…)
- `PIVOT` does turn rows into columns. For it to work, only a single value might be returned for each place in the matrix. Any grouping function will serve the purpose in general; choice does depend on the specific problem. Not an issue here, yes.
- You might want to check the effect of adding `ALL` towards `SELECT tName name FROM teacher UNION ALL SELECT sName FROM student`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b50c)

Comment: Hey ;) Thank you very much, that works awesome. Thanks for editing my question too! That was totally what i needed. Now it works, and im tryin to understand it.
The WITH helps me to name a subselect right? so that i can use it later in the query? What is the function of Trunk() and Rank()? Rank() ranks the object, and when its the same, its the same rank, am i right? Whats the meaning of trunk()?. Well, at least i understand that Mod(), i got it earlier but wasnt able to implement it right. U named these two rows rw and cl. What does they stand for? The last thing is the PIVOT() function,

Comment: how does this work? Why i need to use the group function MIN()? The next block just tells oracle, if cl=1 give in to the first column, if cl=2 second and so on, am i right?

Comment: Okay i found out that i not have to use Min(), max() would also possible. Am i right, when i say that i just have to use a Group Function to make the Compiler happy?:)